# Read the list of embedded files present within a word document using ASP.NET MVC and C# and OpenXML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openxml

I have a word document(.docx) which has an .exe file embedded into it. I am trying to upload the file and read the embedded file content names (here in this case .exe). I tried the following code snippet using ASP.NET MVC and C# without OpenXML .But here I am getting the `pkg.GetParts()` null value.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult UploadFile()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    try
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string _FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            //string _path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), _FileName);
            //file.SaveAs(_path);

            Package pkg = Package.Open(_FileName);


            System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(_FileName);


            string extension = fi.Extension.ToLower();

            string embeddingPartString = string.Empty;


            if ((extension == ".docx") || (extension == ".dotx") || (extension == ".docm") || (extension == ".dotm"))
            {
                embeddingPartString = "/word/embeddings/";
            }
            else if ((extension == ".xlsx") || (extension == ".xlsm") || (extension == ".xltx") || (extension == ".xltm"))
            {
                embeddingPartString = "/excel/embeddings/";
            }
            else
            {
                embeddingPartString = "/ppt/embeddings/";
            }


            // Get the embedded files names. 
            foreach (PackagePart pkgPart in pkg.GetParts())
            {
                if (pkgPart.Uri.ToString().StartsWith(embeddingPartString))
                {
                    string fileName1 = pkgPart.Uri.ToString().Remove(0, embeddingPartString.Length);
                    //chkdLstEmbeddedFiles.Items.Add(fileName1);
                }
            }
            pkg.Close();


        }
        ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded Successfully!!";
        return View();
    }
    catch
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "File upload failed!!";
        return View();
    }
}
```

Can anyone provide their guidance to resolve this issue.